# Update a column value based on another column value with SubSonic 2.1/2.2

Tags: subsonic, subsonic2.2

I have the following code using SubSonic 2.1/2.2

```
SubSonic.Update(<some table>)
.Set(<column A>)
.EqualTo(<column B>).
Where(condition...).Execute()
```

I would like to change it to update "column A" with the value of "column B" + 1.
How can I do it with this syntax.

Is there a better SubSonic syntax to achieve the same thing:

ColumnA = ColumnB + 1

Or even

ColumnA = ColumnA + a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **SetExpression** instead of **Set** will solve the problem

```
SubSonic.Update(<some table>)
.SetExpression("columnA")
.EqualTo("columnB + 1").
Where(condition...).Execute()
```